# javascript global variable (with html template)

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, variables, global

How can I create a global variable in javascript?

I need to use an index value (it's incrementation value) on a field's id inside a "for", but the index keeps the "0" value on every loop.

It's on a HTML template.

I was told that I can solve that by making the index as a local variable.

Edit: I'm trying to put the incremented index values on a field of the loop of this JQuery FileUpload API: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Just drop the `var` keyword, and it's automagically global? It's not a fix for issues like this, you should figure out what scope really is!

Comment: I don't think global variables are what you should be using for this. Could you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Variables that are declared outside of a function will be global.

Comment: What if they are declared inside an objects scope ?

Comment: as far as I know, variables only have function scope if declared within a function....so creating an object still keeps the variable limited to that object as opposed to the entire script. Though declaring a public class could establish a path.

Answer (score 0):

I use `window.variableName = 'some Value'` to declare and access a global variable from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are global unless explicitly defined with `var`. You can make a variable accessible to external functions by attaching it to the `window` object, though it's considered bad practice since you are polluting the global scope.